# python и вывод текста. Как сделать текст на выходе Жирным или увеличить шрифт

Tags: python

Есть фрагмент текста, который необходимо обработать. В около конечной части кода выглядит примерно так:

```
param = "500.10"
text = f"на данный момент {param} такой то"
```

В данный вывод собирается в кучу строк и передается почтовому клиенту. Хотелось бы именно в текстовом фрагменте сам param выделять отдельным цветом или жирным и увеличить шрифт. Подскажите, можно ли реализовать без привлечения каких либо дополнительных библиотек?

Comment: Если вы можете передать в ваш почтовый клиент контент в виде html, то форматируйте текст как html

Comment: передаю посредством smtlib библиотеки
```
msg_main = "\r\n".join(("Subject: %s" %tema,"", text_body))
```

Comment: Вариант решения https://stackoverflow.com/a/882770/15035314

Comment: Да видел это решение. Но привлечение этой библиотеки мне отказали. )

Answer (score 0):

```
param = "500.10"
text = f"на данный момент\033[1m {param}\033[0m такой то"
print(text)
```

---

на данный момент **500.10** такой то

Здесь Bold не передается, примерно так выглядит.
Но при копировании слетает, так что лучше html

Comment: Без использования других библиотек это единственное решение.

Comment: Какие библиотеки бы посоветовали?

Answer (score 0):

С помощью библиотеки [*colorama*](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/):

```py
from colorama import Style
param = '500.10'
print('на данный момент ' + Style.BRIGHT + param + Style.RESET_ALL + ' такой то')
```